# Remove and block unwanted postback string

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Google webmaster page found duplicate content due to the following:

If we take this dynamic search page example.com/armin-music-page-1

google found post back string after "page-1" as shown in example below

example.com/armin-music-page-1$dneix

example.com/armin-music-online-page-1&q=sa=x&ei=-a

example.com/music-dance-club-mix-page-1%balbla

example.com/armin-search-page-1#einx
and many random postback strings

My question, how do i remove or redirect to 404 anything that is generated after "page-1" via apache mod_rewrite .htaccess so google finds clean url only

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get rid of the stuff after `page-1` by redirecting to the URL where that's removed:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+-page-1)(.+)$ /$1? [L,R=301]
```

(rule needs to be near the top of the htaccess file)

Or if you want to send to 404:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+-page-1)(.+)$ - [L,R=404]
```

But one thing you can't do is deal with requests that look like this:

```
example.com/armin-search-page-1#einx
```

because the `#einx` part of the URL **is never sent to the server**, so there's no way for the server to match against it. All apache and mod_rewrite sees is `/armin-search-page-1`.

Comment: @Fixa Sorry, the `.` should have been a `,` in those square brackets